# db4free.net error: "Connection failed: Server sent charset unknown to the client"

Tags: php, mysql, database, bots, telegram

I'm programming a Telegram bot on heroku.com, linked to Dropbox.

I'm trying to connect, using php, to a database located at db4free.net. These are the specifications of the database:

```
Database server

Server: MySQL 8.0 Server (127.0.0.1 via TCP/IP)
Server type: MySQL
Server connection: SSL is used without certification authority      
Server version: 8.0.11 - MySQL Community Server - GPL
Protocol version: 10
User: trial4life@localhost
Server charset: UTF-8 Unicode (utf8)

Web server

Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu)
Database client version: libmysql - mysqlnd 5.0.12-dev - 20150407 - $Id: b5c5906d452ec590732a93b051f3827e02749b83 $
PHP extension: mysqliDocumentation curlDocumentation mbstringDocumentation
PHP version: 7.0.30-0ubuntu0.16.04.1
```

Whenever I try to connect to the database (remember that the php script is launched from heroku.com), I get the following error:

```
Connection failed: Server sent charset unknown to the client. Please, report to the developers.
```

I've read that I could try to edit the `my.cnf` file to adapt the utf encode, but the database is hosted by db4free.net, so I don't think I could fix in that way.

How can I fix?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue (on Windows). I upgraded my PHP version to 7.2.7, and the problem faded away.

https://github.com/laradock/laradock/issues/1130